# PDF Merging and Extracting all pageAnnotations

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a couple of scenarios when i merge pdfs and also when i extract annotations:

- Insert a doc between a pageRange :

  - For Example:

    pdf_1 (pages 1 -> 3) , pdf_2 , pdf_2 , pdf_1 (pages 4 -> 5)

    So, i have tried two ways to achieve this:

    - Using `Splitter` class to get the subdocs, and use `PDFMerger.appendDocument` (This approach takes memory and time).
    - Other approach was to loop over pages for each document and add (import) pages needed to a newly created document. (this approach is much faster and takes less memory)

  My question is there any other way that is better than these 2 approaches, and also i want to preserve the formFields as much as i can, which takes us to the second question.

I want to parse the pdf document, so that the output would be like this :

```
        {
            "pageAnnotations": {
                "radioButton": [], // should contain all radio buttons annotations with exportedValues, flags ... also if radio has two checks, this means that two objects would exist in this array.
                "pushButton": [],
                "textBox": [],
                "checkBox": [],
                "choiceBox": []
            },
            "pageNumber": 1,
            "rect": {
                "rotation": 0.0,
                "offsetX": 0.0,
                "offsetY": 0.0,
                "width": 25.5,
                "height": 33.0
            }
        }
```

I managed to get the above structure, but it relies on the existence of `acroForms` and `pageAnnotations` by looping over the `fieldTree` and getting the `widgets` for `terminal` fields then link a `widget` on the field with a page.

The Issue here is that in the case of merged pdfs as above , the formFields are removed, but the page Annotations are preserved, so i cannot rely on the parsing explained above any more.

What i need is to parse pdfs based on pageAnnotations (page by page) without relying on the acroForm anymore. ???

(Sorry i cannot share any code or pdfs,  (company policy))

Comment: Actually the losing of the AcroForm structure already is an issue because pdf processors thereafter don't need to find your firm field anymore.

Comment: So, i cannot parse ( meaning extract type(radio, cgeck, text ...), required, comb, value, exportedValues, flags, names ) only based on the page annotations ?? 

I have tried such a pdf (one with no forms, but each page has its annotations) with a JavaScript library `pdfJS` and it extracts all page annotations without acroforms ?

Comment: Of course you can find the form fields (unless invisible or on a page template, not a page) by starting from the annotations of all the pages, but *don't expect others to do so*, too. Thus, if those pdfs only are and ever will be processed by your software, that may be ok, but if there is the slightest chance that other pdf processors may have to process those pdfs any time, you may be told that your pdfs are broken and asked to repair them which can be embarrassing and cause much work to do.

Comment: @mkl , Thanks a lot, but can you give me an example how to do so, as i told you, i tried from pageAnnotations, but i could not get all required data, like  exportedValues in case of radio button, also could not differentiate between different button types ..., and in case of pdfs built with hierarchical fields , how can i check if the annotation is the terminal one or the leaf (bearing in mind no acroforms at all, so `cataglog.getAcroForms() = null` ).

I  really appreciate your response, and the help you're giving me.

Comment: @mkl , Also what is the difference between a page template and a page ?

Comment: I am interested in widget annotations for now. @mkl

Comment: *"bearing in mind no acroforms at all"* - how about rebuilding the **AcroForm** dictionary by collecting the root form fields starting from the annotations? Thereafter you can use the normal pdfbox classes for AcroForm management.

Comment: @mkl, So, you suggest i build the AcroForm dict from pageAnnotations ? i am really not looking for building AcroForm, i am trying to get all the page annotations (widgets) page by page, but in some cases i cannot get some data about some annotations. And using methods for PDAnnotation class does not return right values, like values, names, ... (and also differentiating between different Btn annotations).

Pardon me i am not a pdf expert.

Comment: An example to what i mean, assume i am using the MergerUtility with OPTIZIMED_MODE, which copies pages from sources to destination, and don't account for the AcroForms in any way, and the merged Document would be parsed the way i described , only by annotations existing on each page, i want each annotations name, value, rectangle, type (Tx, Ch, Btn (radio, check)) and all data related to each button. @mkl

Comment: I am sorry to bother you, but could you show me a snippet that does that, as an example?, Another question if you may, Why merging pdfs whether with mergerUtility or if i merged them page by page takes a lot of memory (heap size jumps from 20 MB to 250 MB for merging 10 docs (5 pages each) and each one of size 700KB ??

Comment: Most of those entries are inheritable. Thus, you'll have to decent to the root field entries anyways. So you are only inches away from rebuilding the AcroForm.

Comment: *"could you show me ..."* - on the holiday today and during the weekend I'm most likely not at my PC, merely online on my smart phone, so it's very unlikely I'll be able to show any code these days.

Comment: @mkl, I am Sorry :) , Enjoy your weekend.

Comment: Ok, at the PC for a few minutes. You say you're *"using the MergerUtility with OPTIZIMED_MODE"*. `OPTIMIZE_RESOURCES_MODE` is a `DocumentMergeMode` in which it is documented to only copy *Page content and resources*. Actually it also copies annotations but not properly (e.g. it does not adjust their references back to the page if present). Thus, I would not recommend using that mode if annotations may be involved.

Comment: @mkl  so the LEGACY_MODE is recommended if the Annotations are involved ?. But again it consumes a lot of memory if i used the LEGACY_MODE.

Comment: I ended up merging docs page by page like optimized_mode does, but did not use the `cloner` object, So, the destination doc has references from the sources, and after that i merge the AcroForms (using your mergeAcroforms Fun) for each source on the destination Doc. So `dest` now has srcs pages `COSObject`, and acroforms which reference the pages annotations.

Comment: *"so the LEGACY_MODE is recommended if the Annotations are involved"* - well, if the documentation of the alternative apparently implies that the alternative does not take annotations into account, this somehow does recommend using the legacy mode... to me that OPTIMIZED mode currently looks like a proof-of-concept only. Which of course means that it may be developed further over time and eventually be generally useful.